# Different answers when calculating factorial using iteration and recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, iteration, factorial

First time poster here, I hope that this question is acceptable.

As a small test I wrote an application that calculates the factorial of a number using both iteration and recursion.  This seemed to work fine except when trying to calculate the factorial for numbers greater then 24.

For example, when calculating the factorial of 24 both methods give the correct answer of 62044840173323941.

When calculating the factorial of 25 however, the answers differ.  The recursive method gives the answer as 1.5511210043330986e+025 while the iterative method gives the answer as 1.5511210043330984e+025.

According to Wolfram Alpha the correct answer should be the same as the iterative method, so why the discrepancy between the functions? I asked my colleagues and they also are unable to explain the behaviour.

```
#define TEST_CASE 25

double GetFactorialRecursive(double i)
{   
    if (i == 1)
    return i;
    else
    return i * GetFactorialRecursive(i - 1);
}

double GetFactorialIterative(double i)
{
    double result = 1.0;
    for (; i > 0; --i)
        result *= i;
    return result;
}

int main ()
{
    double recres = 0, itrres = 0; 
    recres = GetFactorialRecursive(TEST_CASE);
    itrres = GetFactorialIterative(TEST_CASE);

    if (recres != itrres)
        std::cout << "Error" << "\n";
    std::cout << std::setprecision(25) << "Recursion: " << recres << ", Iteration: " << itrres << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: I tried this out myself. Same result, also notable that the two numbers only differ by one bit: `Recursion: 15511210043330986055303168 [4529a940c33f6121]` and `Iteration: 15511210043330983907819520 [4529a940c33f6120]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recursive version calculates 5 * (4 * (3 * (2 * 1)))

The iterative version calculates 1 * (2 * (3 * (4 * 5)))

The difference in the order of operations changes how the floating point arithmetic rounds, resulting in a different result.

Comment: The reason why floating point is rounding in this case is because the `double` type can only hold up to about 15-17 significant digits, and `n!` tend to have much more than 15-17 digits in them for even relatively small values of `n`. Wolfram|Alpha on the other hand uses a completely different method other than `double` when handling these kinds of quantities.

Answer (score 5):

The type `double` is [not an exact type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_exact).  It promises to be an approximation of the correct value.

So both implementations are not guaranteed to be exact.

As your implementations are concerned there are **two** factors that *could* cause different answers.

1. you are ordering the multiplication differently.
2. Your iterative version performs all the math in the same variable.  Intel-compatible architectures (x86 and x86-64) use **80 bits** of accuracy in their floating-point registers, and that accuracy is maintained until the register is stored in memory.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the register issue, it's a PITA that an optimization (keeping the variable in register instead of putting it back in memory) can actually change the observable behavior of the program :(

Answer (score 2):

The order of multiplications is different, giving different results due to floating-point rounding.

If you change the `for` loop to go from `1` to `i` (rather than from `i` to `1`), you should get the same result as from the recursive version.

Comment: As pointed out by Drew Dormann, actually you might not unless the register <-> memory transition are also exactly the same after code generation since registers tend (on x86 architectures) to have better precision...